# Web page gets stuck in HTML loader in some device

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to 'HTML Loader'. So I have implemented an HTML Loader to my web page and for some device it is working fine. But in some mobile device (not all) the page is getting stuck at the loader. As I said, I am new to this 'HTML Loader' thing, I just copied and pasted the code for loader. Here is the code. Where and what I need to modify to solve this device/browser dependency issue??

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  // Animate loader off screen
  $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

```css
.no-js #loader { 
  display: none;  
}

.js #loader { 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 100px; 
  top: 0; 
}

.se-pre-con {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url(img/Preloader.gif) center no-repeat #fff;
}
```

```html
my contents
<div class="se-pre-con"></div>
    
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>
```

Comment: In the snippet it appears to be working fine. Have your really declared a div outside the body tag?

Comment: @SuperDJ It is working fine on most of the devices. But in few devices the problem is appearing.

Comment: Some browsers like chrome are very forgiving in that they solve problems on their own but other browser like Internet Exploded require perfect markup